# Trigger/send email when any contact open Email sent via Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data-views

I have a scenario where in I wish to send an alert email to a specific Email-ID whenever any contact opens the email sent from the journey.

As of now I think the best approach as below,
Create an Automation which runs daily.
Use SQL activity to use Data views [_Opens and _JourneyActivity]

Can anyone provide any other approach or a simple solution?

Comment: You can use webhooks when a OPEN event occurs then make an API call to send an email

Comment: @EazyE thanks... But is it possible to use Event notification service to check email opens for the email sent via multi step journey?... If yes can you please provide any reference links.